# immutable variable for unit tests

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have some test cases which rely on the same variable `foo`

```
from unittest import TestCase

# actually FOO is imported because it is quite big
FOO = {'key_a': 'aaa', 'key_b': 'bbb'}

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = FOO

    def test_a(self):
        self.foo['key_a'] = 'ccc'
        self.assertEqual(self.foo['key_a'], 'ccc')

    def test_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.foo['key_a'], 'aaa')
```

the issue I have is that once I change the value in `test_a` to

```
        self.foo['key_a'] = 'ccc'
```

the value "stays" this way for all subsequent tests. the assert in `test_b` fails because the value of `self.foo['key_a']` remains at `'ccc'`

how do I have to write the test case so `self.foo` is `{'key_a': 'aaa', 'key_b': 'bbb'}` in all tests?

Comment: I don't think your example demonstrates your problem. `self.foo` is set in the `setUp` method before every test, so changes in `test_a` should not affect `test_b`.

Comment: Test cases (methods) are not sand-boxed. Variables set up in `setUp` are shared.

Comment: @Siegmeyer I didn't say the methods are sandboxed, I said that the setUp method runs before each test. Changes to `self.foo` in `test_a` won't have any effect on `test_b`, because the setUp method will run before `test_b` runs and set `self.foo` again. Try running the example - both tests pass.

Comment: @Alasdair, apologies for this. I simplified my example to much and the effect did not show with the initial example I provided (as you noted from the beginning). I was able to update the code only now. this time it shows the effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `self.foo = FOO` in the `setUp` method, you are not copying the dictionary, you are just assigning it to `self.foo`. When you set `self.foo['a']`, this is altering the original dictionary `FOO`, so it affects other tests.

You could avoid this problem by copying the dictionary in the `setUp` method.

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = FOO.copy()
```

If the dictionary contains other mutable values, then you might have to use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

```
import copy

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = copy.deepcopy(FOO)
```

Comment: thanks! also for the `self.foo = copy.deepcopy(FOO)` tip! that did the trick!